# cache page depending on selected language

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have mvc4 app which is available on two languages.

Now I have problem with caching, I tried with output caching like

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByHeader="Accept-Language")]
public ActionResult Home() {...}
```

but this not solve anything, page is cached and when I change language nothing happens, previously cached page still remains until cache expires. I'm not sure that this `VaryByHeader="Accept-Language` is matched with my pages localization setup.

When user clicks on a language flag some integer value (which represents current language) is stored inside cookie, and helper is called which reads cookie and sets corresponding language using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ...`

so how can I cache page depending on selected language, if it's of any value there are only two languages.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a custom parameter to the OutputCache for the language in order for this to work.

Take a look at [this blog post](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) which does an excellent job explaining the process, specifically the `OutputCache and Localization` section.

The blog post is geared towards MVC2 though, but it should also work for MVC4 just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Override `GetVaryByCustomString` in `global.asax.cs`:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string value)
{
     if (value.Equals("lang"))
     {
         return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
     }
     return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context,value);
}
```

Now write your `OutputCache` over the `Action` like below code:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=3600,VaryByParam="none", VaryByCustom="lang")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     // My Codes .... ;)
     return View();
}
```

> **Note:**
>   In my case I has been written the *setting language* codes in a custom `ControllerFactory` class and it was **not** firing **before** `GetVaryByCustomString` method (it was firing **after** it) and this issue cause **failure** in caching based on the user selected language in the Action. So I moved my *setting language* codes to **`Application_BeginRequest`** method inside `Global.asax.cs` file and now it works.

---

> I wrote this answer based on the [link](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) that @DimitryKhaykin mentioned in his answer to write the answer inside SO.